# We Can't Go Back in Time, but We Can Reformat It: How to Using Bootstrap & Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I pulled this code from [here](http://www.davehulihan.com/bootstrap-datetimepicker-and-rails/), but then when I click on the date input form the calendar doesn't pop up. I configured gem 'bootstrap-datepicker-rails' and added the necessary code to application.css (*= require bootstrap-datepicker) & application.js (//= require bootstrap-datepicker).

If anyone has any **suggestions to fix this or provide any alternatives** I'm all ears. I just want to be able to use a calendar popup menu so that people can choose the deadline date for their self-imposed goals. Even if the calendar popup doesn't work out at the very least I want a nicer layout than the default date selection form.

It's my 24th birthday today so if anyone isn't hungover out there please give me this gift. Thanks and Happy New Year!

**config/initializers/form.rb**

```html
module ActionView
  module Helpers
    class FormBuilder 
      def date_select(method, options = {}, html_options = {})
        existing_date = @object.send(method) 
        formatted_date = existing_date.to_date.strftime("%F") if existing_date.present?
        @template.content_tag(:div, :class => "input-group") do    
          text_field(method, :value => formatted_date, :class => "form-control datepicker", :"data-date-format" => "YYYY-MM-DD") +
          @template.content_tag(:span, @template.content_tag(:span, "", :class => "glyphicon glyphicon-calendar") ,:class => "input-group-addon")
        end
      end

      def datetime_select(method, options = {}, html_options = {})
        existing_time = @object.send(method) 
        formatted_time = existing_time.to_time.strftime("%F %I:%M %p") if existing_time.present?
        @template.content_tag(:div, :class => "input-group") do    
          text_field(method, :value => formatted_time, :class => "form-control datetimepicker", :"data-date-format" => "YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm A") +
          @template.content_tag(:span, @template.content_tag(:span, "", :class => "glyphicon glyphicon-calendar") ,:class => "input-group-addon")
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

**_form.html.erb**

```html
<%= form_for(@goal) do |f| %>
  <% if @goal.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@goal.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this goal from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @goal.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="america">
<form>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.text_field :name, class: 'form-control', placeholder: 'Enter Goal' %>
  </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Deadline:</label>
        <%= f.date_select :deadline %>
    </div>

<div class="america2">
  <%= button_tag(type: 'submit', class: "btn") do %>
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
  <% end %>

  <%= link_to goals_path, class: 'btn' do %>
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
  <% end %>

  <%= link_to @goal, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }, class: 'btn' do %>
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
  <% end %>
</div>
  </form>
</div>
<% end %>
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Do you call `$('.datepicker').datetimepicker();` somewhere?

Comment: I added it now to the form view but still no luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realize you can't use f.date_select with bootstrap datepicker, instead use f.text_field.